# How can I move the gnome dock to the left side?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, dock

I installed the gnome panel:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/17/dock/

but its on the right side, which is quite annoying becaus it alway popps up when using the scrollbar.
How can I move it to the left?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dock position left
```

For 3.2 users, here is another way:

Type in a terminal:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js
```

About line 44 find:

```
const DOCK_POSITION = PositionMode.RIGHT;
```

change to

```
const DOCK_POSITION = PositionMode.LEFT;
```

Save, exit, refresh gnome-shell (hit [Alt+F2] followed by r) and enjoy!

Comment: Could not load schemas from ./schemas: Datei »./schemas/gschemas.compiled« konnte nicht geöffnet werden: open() ist gescheitert: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

Comment: "Datei"=file "konnte nicht geöffnet werden"=could not be opened "Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden"="File or folder not found

Comment: Try with my new edit.

Comment: Keine derartiges Schema »org.gnome.shell.extensions.dock«

Comment: Please, translate.

Comment: Hard^^ I think it wants to say, that "org.gnome.shell.extensions.dock" not exists.

Comment: It MUST exist, if you installed the extension. I've done and have that key in gconf.

Comment: Proof :P http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/lvxh6eni/Screenshotfrom20120621112221.png

Comment: Ok, it seems you're running a different version of gnome-shell. Try with my last edit.

Comment: Im running 3.4.1-0ubuntu2 should I do that anyway?

Comment: First, try searching that key with dconf-editor. Navigate to org.gnome.shell.extensions and tell me if you can find "dock" folder. Then tell me what keys are inside. The other workaround should work, in any case.

Comment: There is no org.gnome.shell.extensions just apps, desktop, schemas & system. Searched the whole folders via Strg+F

Comment: I'm afraid you're searching with gconf-editor, not dconf-editor...

Comment: There is no extensions. Just calendar, clock, keybindings, keyboard, overrides, recorder

Comment: That looks very strange. Try the manual solution!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `dconf-editor`
2. Go to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dock`
3. Toggle `autohide` and left/right position from there

Source: [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055526)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on 23.04

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position 'LEFT'
```